# How can I construct equation for this? And solve

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, word-problem

Joseph is 7 times as old as his daughter, In five years times he will be 4 times as old as daughter will be then, what is their ages now?

Comment: You can start trying to formalize the problem, let be $J$ the age of james and $D$ the age of his daughter, then first relation tells you that $J=5*D$, the second that $J+5 = 4*(D+5)$ then just solve the system

Comment: Is it correct the first equation $J=5*D$

Comment: sorry I red 5, i meant $J=7*D$

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$ be the daughter’s current age. Then the father’s current age is $7x$.

Five years from now the daughter’s age will be $x+5$, the father’s $7x+5$.

What information hasn't been used yet?

> $7x+5=4(x+5)$

Answer (score 0):

$$j = 7d$$
$$J = 4D$$
$$J = j+5$$
$$D = d+5$$